# submitting one of multiple dynamically created froms on a page

Tags: jquery

I searched (trust me!) but for some reason, haven't quite found the answer I'm after, though I'm pretty sure I'm not asking a unique question.

The background:
I'm dynamically creating some update forms based on a person's marriage status. Given that a person could have been partnered or married several times in their lifetime, there could be multiple partners associated with a single person. OK.

So the *HTML* form (not the real thing, but an emulation of):

```
<form id="updateDetails" action="..." method="...">

<input type="text" id="partnerName" value="John Smith" name="partnerName">
<input type="text" id="marriageDate" value="01-01-1987" name="marriageDate">
...
<input type="submit" id="updatePartner" ...>

</form>
```

There could be **multiple** copies of this form on the one page all with the same form id and the same form elements. Only the values are different.

The *jQuery*:

```
$(function() {

    $("#updatePartner").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
//Some form validation is done here - if field not filled in, spit out error message

    var partnerName = $("partnerName").val();
    var marriageDate = $("marriageDate").val();
    var data_string = 'partnerName='+ partnerName+ '&marriageDate=' + marriageDate;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "theProcessFile.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
            // do some fancy jQuery stuff here
           }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

My Question: What do I do to the existing jQuery code to make sure it **only** picks and submits the form elements from where the submit button (#updatePartner) was clicked.

I believe I should be using something like

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
```

but for the life of me (I am not the most fluent with javascript) can't quite work out how I would then make use of this variable to submit (bind) the form values just for this particular form. Not asking anything difficult and I'd assume this is real basic.

Note: all the code works (including the php processing script to update the db) - it does exactly what it should do if there is *only one form*. As soon as a second form appears, it gets confused.

Thanks in advance for any help, but please don't assume I will understand brief one liner answers :-(

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you CANNOT have two or more elements with the same id.

You should change your code to:

```
<form action="..." method="..." class="ajaxed">

<input type="text" value="John Smith" name="partnerName">
<input type="text" value="01-01-1987" name="marriageDate">
...
<input type="submit"  ...>

</form>
```

and

```
$(function() {

    $("form.ajaxed").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "theProcessFile.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            // do some fancy jQuery stuff here
           }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoo Hoo! Thanks for that - it worked a treat! Mind you, still took me a bit of messing around. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot have multiple elements with the same id**.  It doesn't look like you're even referencing the form by id, so just drop it altogether.

I'd say the best way to select the relevant form would be:

```
var form = $(this).parent("form");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //this prevents the form from submitting correctly
    return false;
})
```

instead